# Convert Boolean integer to true/false values using knex

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I would like my project_complete column to return either true or false but I seem to be getting 1/0 when I try and get data through my API

I created the table to take in boolean values and default to false

```
   .createTable('proj', tbl => {
        tbl.increments('proj_id')
        tbl.string('name', 64).notNullable()
        tbl.string('description', 64)
        tbl.boolean('project_complete').defaultTo(false);
    })
```

and return all data from this table using this endpoint:

```
function getAll() {
    return db('projects');
}
```

When I retrieve my data I get this:

```
[{"proj_id":1,"name":"Testing","description":"Something something","project_complete":0}]
```

This is my desired result:

```
[{"proj_id":1,"name":"Testing","description":"Something something","project_complete":false}]
```

Database: SQLite

Comment: Hi! please provide more information regarding your database, for instance boolean behavior varies if you're using mysql/mariadb or sqlite. also i would suggest to make the boolean column not nullable too, so you avoid the unwanted tri-state logic.

Comment: @Sombriks I am using sqlite

Comment: actually the problem seems very active, affecting mysql too: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1240 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004328/knex-js-mysql-casting-integer-into-boolean-for-bulk-select